# Comment utiliser « ce contre » ?

Tags: prépositions, pronoms-relatifs

Est-que la phrase « Ce contre ils se battent, c'est la répression » est correcte ?

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence grammaticale entre cette phrase et « Ce qu'ils se battent contre, c'est la répression » ?

Answer (score 6):

Il manque deux mots à cette phrase:

> Ce contre quoi ils se battent, c'est la répression.

L'autre proposition n'a pas de sens.

> <s>Ce qu'ils battent contre, c'est la répression</s>.

Answer (score 3):

En français **actuel**, les deux phrases sont **incorrectes**. La deuxième totalement.

À noter qu'en ancien français, certaines inversions étaient possibles, et certains mots omis (ce fait, ...)

**La première devrait être corrigée ainsi:**

> Ce contre quoi ils se battent, c'est la répression.

Cette forme est du type:

*Ce* (pronom) + relative (qui précise ce), *c'est* + explications.

Exemples:

> Ce que je vois, c'est la mairie.
>
> Ce que je mange, c'est …
>
> Ce à quoi je pense, …
>
> Ce dont je parle, …
>
> Ce sur quoi je saute, …

*Ce* désigne un objet. Pour des personnes on écrirait « Ceux contre qui » or « Celles contre qui ».

*Contre*, *à*, *sur*, etc., sont des prépositions qui s'utiliseraient dans la forme affirmative comme ceci :

> Je me bats contre cela => ce contre quoi je me bats.
>
> Je saute sur cela => ce sur quoi je saute.

Comment: « Ce contre qui je me bats » est incorrect. C'est soit « [Celui] contre qui je me bats », soit « Ceux contre qui je me bat »

Comment: @jlliagre , effectivement, merci pour les corrections.